# SQL Server update query not working, however, SQL says the rows were affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL Server 2000 database with a table named `Voters`.  One column in the table (`PrecinctCode` of type `varchar(10)`) is supposed to have a 4 digit code similar to `A111` or `D109`, but some rows have a value of `'999'`. The rows with value `'999'` have the correct number in a different column (`FaultCode` of type `varchar(50)`). I want to copy the values from `FaultCode` to `PrecinctCode` when `PrecinctCode = 999`.

I ran this query

```
UPDATE Voters
SET PrecinctCode = FaultCode
WHERE (PrecinctCode = '999')
```

A message appears saying "3031 rows affected" but the affected rows still show 999 in the `PrecinctCode` column. I connect to the DB with Windows Authentication under the administrator account, so I don't think its a security issue.

Has anyone had an update query that would not update rows?

**EDIT**

I tried this query to retrieve the schema, it gave me nothing useful though.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where   TABLE_NAME like '%Voters%'
```

Would just posting the table design work? if not can you tell me a query to run to retrieve the information you need? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running this?  If it's within a transaction, is the transaction being committed?

Comment: Trying to run this directly in SQL in the query analyzer.

Comment: That should work.  Can you post the schema for this table?

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database?

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 database at this site.

Comment: Got to ask.  You are sure FaultCode <> 999.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to commit after the update

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a SELECT first so you are certain what you are asking for:

```
SELECT FaultCode, PrecinctCode FROM Voters WHERE PrecinctCode = '999';
```

N.B. that if length of FaultCode exceeds 10 chars your UPDATE will fail.

Answer (score 1):

For grins please try this

```
UPDATE Voters
SET PrecinctCode = FaultCode
WHERE PrecinctCode = '999' and FaultCode <> '999'
```

Or try

```
UPDATE Voters
SET PrecinctCode = RTRIM (FaultCode)
WHERE PrecinctCode = '999'
```

And

```
select *, len(FaultCode)
from Voters
WHERE PrecinctCode = '999' 
  and PrecinctCode <> FaultCode
```