# UPDATE SQL Query returning misleading response

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am doing a simple UPDATE SQL Query into a database using nodejs as shown below:

```
conn.query("UPDATE room SET `join_id`=? WHERE `id`=?", [join, cfid], function (e, r) {
    console.log(e, r);
    //e null; r object;
});
```

The response `r` from the query returns this:

```
OkPacket {                                                                                                                                
  fieldCount: 0,                                                                                                                               
  affectedRows: 1,                                                                                                                             
  insertId: 0,                                                                                                                                 
  serverStatus: 34,                                                                                                                            
  warningCount: 0,                                                                                                                             
  message: '(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0',                                                                                        
  protocol41: true,                                                                                                                            
  changedRows: 1 
}
```

Yet after the `OKPacket` response, I see no change in the database and therefore the rest of my code malfunctions. I've spent hours researching on this issue and found just a question from two years ago which was not concluded: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920490/sql-server-update-query-not-working-however-sql-says-the-rows-were-affected)

Comment: Do you perhaps have transactions turned on?

Comment: What are transactions?

Comment: If you have several changes to a database that must either all succeed or all fail, you start a transaction first. If at some point there's a failure, the transaction is "rolled back" to avoid inconsistencies. If everything succeeds, your transaction is "committed" to save the changes. See [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have autocommit turned off, perhaps in the MySQL server's my.cnf file or some other way. To check, run code along the lines of this:

```
let sql = "SHOW GLOBAL variables LIKE 'autocommit'";
connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result, 'global');
});

let sql2 = "SHOW variables LIKE 'autocommit'";
connection.query(sql2, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result, 'local');
});
```

Your console should output

```
[ RowDataPacket { Variable_name: 'autocommit', Value: 'ON' } ] 'global'
[ RowDataPacket { Variable_name: 'autocommit', Value: 'ON' } ] 'local'
```

But if autocommit is 'OFF', you have your answer.